# Graduated color display of overlapping polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, overlapping-features, display

Is there a way to display overlapping polygons in a graduated color symbology based on the level of overlap within the same feature layer? For example, in one area of the map there are two polygons that overlap, so the bottom polygon is light blue and the top polygon is medium blue, but in another area there is three polygons that overlap, the bottom is light blue, middle is medium blue and the top dark blue....etc in ArcMap
Basically the bottom most polygon is the lightest and the top most is the darkest.

EDIT-- Is this possible to do programmatically? ArcObjects?Python?

Comment: Topologically speaking, this would seem impossible, since it would be easy to arrange "A overlaps B overlaps C overlaps A". If it is possible in a limited way, it would require some sophisticated analysis. What have you attempted so far? Note that render order is not required to be the same, so the definition of "top" will take some work.

Comment: I do not have the workable data just yet, just able to view it online. Just trying to wrap my brain around a possible solution!

Comment: I think that you should include a picture that illustrates what you are trying to describe.

Comment: I've been meaning to add an image but trying to figure out how to do that! I also think I have figured it out for the most part, but since it is a larger data set I am looking to simplify things as much as possible

Comment: Success! I used the Spaghetti and Meatballs method by Dale Honeycutt. This worked great!